# How to communicate between two different android apps

Tags: android

I have a Notification started in the system bar by one application(Notification Manager), how can i remove/stop it from another application ? Can i use a broadcast receiver ? Will that work ?

**Description:**
Application A and B is installed. Application B is installed without the launcher option, so it is visible only in settings/apps (so the app is not started). Now App A has to start a service in App B.. Is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617925/how-do-two-android-applications-talk-to-each-other

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638939/android-communication-between-two-applications

Comment: A tcp ip connection over  localhost is allways a option

Comment: @sherif No, that would be completely unnecessary. The android SDK includes many ways for applications to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully something like this will help 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html